# Como eu acesso um pdf file armazenado no R.raw no android SDK?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

Eu acho que está faltando alguma informação para que apareça o arquivo pdf no meu app.
Eu usei a seguinte linha de código dentro do método OnCreate:

```
        PDFView novo = (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        novo.fromAsset("arquivo");
```

Mas ainda assim, não aparece o PDF, quando eu ponho pra rodar o app. O que está faltando? Eu acho que esta string tem que ser referenciada em algum lugar não é? Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Que classe é essa PDFView? Coloque o link para a sua documentação.

Comment: É do git: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer